# Little Problem with *ngFor to Angular HTML

Tags: angular, typescript, indexing, ngfor

i have a probleme with *ngFor . i think index is ko in my tab object "joueurClassement" .it's not a good number sequence .As you can see the picture below. this case works, because indexe is 0,1,2,3,4

in my HTML =>

```
  <tbody>
                <tr *ngFor ="let player of joueurClassement; let i = index">
                <td>{{ player.nom }}</td>
                <td>{{ player.prenom }}</td>
                <td>{{ player.point }}</td>
                <td>{{player.victoire}}</td>
                <td>{{player.defaite}}</td>
                <td>{{player.nbdejeu}}</td>
                </tr>
            </tbody>
```

[*ngFor Ok](https://i.stack.imgur.com/PfNXu.png)

But when the index is not a good sequence number ,  not  0,1,2,3,4 the ngFor is KO.As you can see the picture.My object "joueurClassement " not display in my scream.
[*ngFor Ko](https://i.stack.imgur.com/IWmLR.png)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You're right, your problem is that you're getting *sparse arrays* without consecutive indices.

Here's a solution that'll fix that for you. Use this template:

```html
<table>
  <tbody>
    <ng-container *ngFor="let keyValuePair of joueurClassement | keyvalue; trackBy: trackKeyValuePair">
      <tr *ngIf="keyValuePair.value as player">
        <td>{{player.nom}}</td>
        <td>{{player.prenom}}</td>
        <td>{{player.point}}</td>
        <td>{{player.victoire}}</td>
        <td>{{player.defaite}}</td>
        <td>{{player.nbdejeu}}</td>
      </tr>
    </ng-container>
  </tbody>
</table>
```

I added a `trackBy` function for performance reasons. It looks like this:

```js
class MyComponent {
  trackKeyValuePair(_index, keyValuePair): number {
    return keyValuePair.key;
  }
}
```

[Here's a StackBlitz workspace to show the solution](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-stackoverflow-little-problem-with-ngfor-to-angular-html?file=src/app/app.component.html).

Comment: thanks you so much Lars. it's works !! thanks for you help

Comment: You're welcome. I'm glad to be able to help. Please mark this answer as accepted, if everything worked out 

Comment: hello Lars . Could you help me about a Sort issu .I would like sort this Table and i have chosen to make this feature in my TS component. but i have an issu => https://stackoverflow.com/questions/61293513/issue-about-sort-tab-object-angular-ts-to-display-championship-classificatio       May be it's more easy to do the Sort TAb  it in HTML? thanks Lars for you help

Answer (score 0):

I don't know why this bug happens, but if you want to just do *ngFor, you don't need to add index, like:

```
<tbody>
            <tr *ngFor ="let player of joueurClassement">
            <td>{{ player.nom }}</td>
            <td>{{ player.prenom }}</td>
            <td>{{ player.point }}</td>
            <td>{{player.victoire}}</td>
            <td>{{player.defaite}}</td>
            <td>{{player.nbdejeu}}</td>
            </tr>
        </tbody>
```

You don't need to specify the index, *ngFor could be just like a Foreach

Comment: hey Henrique,  i tryed to remove "let i = index" it doesn"t work .same scream , ngFor don't take in account indexe 4,5,6,9 ...and tab is not display. ;-(

Comment: The index doesn't really matter in *ngFor, can you show your list object? A For just display your list doesn't matter the content in it, but you you need to have the elements of the list defined.

Comment: my list object is define like this:( i retrieve data by firebase)    export class Joueur {
    constructor(public nom: string , 
               public prenom: string,
               public poule: number, 
               public point: number,
               public victoire: number ,               
               public defaite: number,
               public nbdejeu: number
        ){}         => and in my TS  i define  joueurClassement: Joueur[]