# Issue about Sort Tab Object (ANGULAR,TS) to display " championship classification "

Tags: angular, sorting, tabs, compare

[Joueur-Firebase](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ySrRJ.png)

```js
import { Component, OnInit, Output ,HostBinding, OnDestroy} from '@angular/core';
import { Router } from '@angular/router';
import { Joueur } from '../models/joueur.model';
import { Match } from '../models/match.model';
import { JoueurService } from '../services/joueur.service';
import { Subscription } from 'rxjs';
import * as firebase from 'Firebase';




@Component({
  selector: 'app-classement',
  templateUrl: './classement.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./classement.component.scss']
})
export class ClassementComponent implements OnInit, OnDestroy 
{  
  matchClassement: Match[]
  joueurClassement: Joueur[]
  @Output() PouleClassement: any;
  classementSubscription: Subscription;
  matchSubscription: Subscription;
  match: Match;
  constructor(private joueurService: JoueurService, private router: Router) { }

  ngOnInit() {
    this.classementSubscription = this.joueurService.classementSubject.subscribe(
      (joueurClassement: Joueur[]) => {
        this.joueurClassement = joueurClassement;
      }      
    );
    this.PouleClassement = this.joueurService.getPoule();
    this.joueurService.getPouleClassement(this.PouleClassement);
   this.joueurService.emitJoueurClassement();  
   // tri du tableau 
   
   console.table(this.joueurClassement)

   const sortByMapped = (map,compareFn) => (a,b) => compareFn(map(a),map(b));
   const byValue = (a,b) => b - a;
   const toPoint = e => e.point;
   const byPoint = sortByMapped(toPoint,byValue);
   this.joueurClassement.sort(byPoint)

    this.matchSubscription = this.joueurService.matchSubject.subscribe(
     (matchClassement: Match[]) => {
       this.matchClassement = matchClassement;
      }      
  ); 
  this.joueurService.getMatch(this.PouleClassement);
  this.joueurService.emitMatch(); 
  
}
 
  onBack() {
    this.router.navigate(['/poules']);
  }

  onCreatMatch(poule: any) {
     //var P = 1; 
     var TabIndexe = new Array
     
     var NumMatch = 0;
     this.match = new Match(0,'','',0,'','',0);
   
     // fabrication du tableau d'indexe
     var i = 0;
     for ( let J1 in this.joueurClassement ){
          TabIndexe[i] = J1;
          i ++;
     }
     console.table(TabIndexe)
    // creation des matchs
     var P1 = 0;
     var P2 = 1 ;
     console.table(this.joueurClassement)
     while ( P1 < TabIndexe.length ){
       while (P2< TabIndexe.length ){
        var ind = TabIndexe[P1] 
        var ind1 = TabIndexe[(P2)]
        this.match.numMatch = NumMatch
        this.match.joueur1 = this.joueurClassement[ind].nom;
        this.match.prenom1 = this.joueurClassement[ind].prenom;
        this.match.joueur2 = this.joueurClassement[ind1].nom;
        this.match.prenom2 = this.joueurClassement[ind1].prenom;
        this.match.point1 = 0;
        this.match.point2 = 0;
        console.log(  this.match.numMatch + this.match.joueur1 + this.match.joueur2 )
        firebase.database().ref('/poule' + poule + '/' + NumMatch ).set(this.match);
        P2++ 
        NumMatch++
     }
      P1++ 
      P2  = P1 + 1
  }
  }



  ngOnDestroy(){
   this.classementSubscription.unsubscribe();
 }
 
 onSaveMatch(poule,numMatch,joueur1,joueur2){
   this.joueurService.setPoule(poule);
   this.joueurService.setMatch(numMatch,joueur1,joueur2)
  this.router.navigate(['/classement/match']);
 }
 
 trackKeyValuePair(_index, keyValuePair): number {
  return keyValuePair.key;
}



}
```

```js
import { Injectable } from '@angular/core';
import  {Joueur} from '../models/joueur.model';
import  {Match} from '../models/match.model';
import { Subject } from 'rxjs';
import * as firebase from 'Firebase';


@Injectable({
  providedIn: 'root'
})
export class JoueurService {
  
  match: Match[] = [];
  joueur: Joueur[] = [];
  joueurClassement: Joueur[] = [];
  joueurSubject = new Subject<Joueur[]>();
  matchSubject = new Subject<Match[]>();
  classementSubject = new Subject<Joueur[]>();

  constructor() { }
  emitJoueur() {
    this.joueurSubject.next(this.joueur);
  }

  emitJoueurClassement() {
   this.classementSubject.next(this.joueurClassement);
  }
  emitMatch() {
    this.matchSubject.next(this.match);
  }
  saveJoueur(){
    firebase.database().ref('/joueurs').set(this.joueur); 
  }

 
  getJoueur(){
    firebase.database().ref('/joueurs').on('value', (data) => {
      this.joueur = data.val() ? data.val() : [] ;
      this.emitJoueur();
    });
  }

  getSingleJoueur(id: number){
      return new Promise(
         (resolve, reject) => {
          firebase.database().ref( '/joueurs/' + id).once('value').then(
            (data) =>{
              resolve(data.val());
            }
            ,(error) =>{
              reject(error);
            }
          );
        }
      );
    }
 creatNewJoueur(newJoueur: Joueur , poule){
      this.joueur.push(newJoueur);
      this.saveJoueur();
      this.emitJoueur();
    }


  removeJoueur(joueur: Joueur){
      const JoueurIndexToRemove = this.joueur.findIndex(
        (joueurEl) => {
          if(joueurEl === joueur){
            return true;
          }
        }
      );
      this.joueur.splice(JoueurIndexToRemove,1);
      this.saveJoueur();
      this.emitJoueur();
  }
   
  getPouleClassement(poule: any){
    console.log("Service = getPouleClassement" + poule );
    firebase.database().ref('/joueurs').orderByChild('poule')
                                       .equalTo(poule)
                                       .on("value",  (data) => {                                     
                                        this.joueurClassement= (data.val() ? data.val() : []);
                                                                        
                                        this.emitJoueurClassement();                                                                      
                                      });
                                       
   
} 
// sauvegarde et transmission 
  Poule: any;
  setPoule(poule){
      this.Poule =poule;
  } 
//et transmission du numero de poule
  getPoule(){
    let PouleClassement = this.Poule;
      this.clearData();
    return PouleClassement;
    }

  // sauvegarde et transmission 
  nummatch: any;
  joueur1: any;
  joueur2: any;

  setMatch(nummatch,joueur1,joueur2){
      this.nummatch =nummatch;
      this.joueur1 =joueur1;
      this.joueur2 =joueur2;

  } 
//et transmission 
  getNumMatch(){
   let NumMatch = this.nummatch;   
      this.clearData1()
    return NumMatch;
    }  

    getJoueur1(){
     let Joueur1 = this.joueur1;  
         this.clearData2();
       return Joueur1;       
       }  

   getJoueur2(){
    let Joueur2 = this.joueur2;  
        this.clearData3();
      return Joueur2;       
    }  

    clearData(){
      this.Poule = undefined;
    }

    clearData1(){
      this.nummatch = undefined;
    }

    clearData2(){
      this.joueur1 = undefined;
    }
  
  clearData3(){
    this.joueur2 = undefined;
  }
    
    
   
  getMatch(poule)  {
    firebase.database().ref('poule'+ poule).on('value', (data) => {
      this.match = data.val() ? data.val() : [] ;
      this.emitMatch();
  }
  )
}
updateMatch(poule,numMatch,score1,score2){
  firebase.database().ref('poule'+ poule +  '/' + numMatch ).update({point1:score1 , point2:score2 })
  
}

updateJoueur(indexe,point,victoire,defaite,nbdejeu){
  firebase.database().ref('joueurs/'+ indexe  ).update({point:point , victoire:victoire ,defaite:defaite ,nbdejeu: nbdejeu  })
}


}
```

I would like sort a tennis player by **Point** .here  a picture below of my Scream (HTLM + Ts)
[Sort OK](https://i.stack.imgur.com/L5QLF.png)

Below this is **CODE Typescript**: my Object Tab is joueurClassement so i display in HTLM joueurClassement

```
const sortByMapped = (map,compareFn) => (a,b) => compareFn(map(a),map(b));
   const byValue = (a,b) => a - b;
   const toPoint = e => e.point;
   const byPoint = sortByMapped(toPoint,byValue);
   this.joueurClassement.sort(byPoint)
```

But sometime the "sort function" is KO . Here a picture of this issue:
[sort KO](https://i.stack.imgur.com/zIU67.png)
**ERROR TypeError:** this.joueurClassement.sort is not a function

I don't know why sometimes is Ok or KO .May be **index** Tab is bad ?
could you help me please?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Sorry I didn't see the screen shot of your firebase collection. Ok, so if you want to keep your joueurs collection as an array, you could check if your object is an array when you get the result from your service and if not, convert it to array like this

```
let joueurs = data.val();
if (joueurs) {
  if (Array.isArray(joueurs) {
    // joueurs is an array // no conversion needed
  } else {
    // Assume that joueurs is an object
    let joueursTable = [];
    // for each "indexed" property "0", "1", etc... add its value to joueursTable
    Object.keys(joueurs)
    .filter(key => Number.isInteger(Number(key)))
    .forEach(key => joueursTable[key] = joueurs[key]);
    console.log(joueursTable) // --> Here should have your object converted to array
  }
} else {
  // empty result 
}
```

Hope it helps you.

Comment: congratulation ! you are the best Thib ! it works .thank s for you help

Comment: you are welcome, glad to help you and good luck for your app development

Comment: last thing, I thought to another option that is clever and more concise and that you could do always nevermind your result is array or object. So instead of all this code (that work) you could just write let joueursTable= Object.assign([ ], joueurs) and you will always get an array

Answer (score 0):

Is it possible to share the code of your component to see where your table is build / initialized, because typically this error should mean that you object joueuerClassement is not an Array so it has not sort function.

Comment: I shared my code TypeScript : classement.componeent.ts and my servive joueur.service.ts.

Comment: Thanks. In your service in the getPouleClassement method you have the folowing code  this.joueurClassement= (data.val() ? data.val() : []);  I think that data.val() return is of type any. Could you check (log or breakpoint) that the data.val() at this point is always array like or is able to be "transformed" as an array ?

Comment: hey Thib you are right ! when you see picture 'Sort Ko' and 'Sort OK' in the first description of the issue you can see the first one 'sort KO' is a object , and the seconde one 'SORT OK' is a Array.So the second question is Why ?i tried again ( creat player for many poule(1,2,3)) and i don't understand why firebase return a array sometine a Object!     so I need to transform object in aray i tried this =>var monTableau = Object.keys(this.joueurClassement).map(function(cle) {
    return [Number(cle), this.joueurClassement[cle]];
}); but unfortunately it doesn't work ...

Answer (score 0):

The way Firebase stores arrays is a little weird and I think you should store your players as a collection instead of an array. When you send an array to firebase database, it will store it as an object like this :

```
// send this array
[{name: 'foo', age: 25}, {name: 'bar', age: 30}]

// Stored like this
{
  "0": {name: "foo", age: 25},
  "1": {name: "bar", age: 30}
}
```

So, technically, when you get your data, firebase database will return an object BUT on certain conditions it should be converted to an array. See this article for more details

https://firebase.googleblog.com/2014/04/best-practices-arrays-in-firebase.html

I think it could be better to use a collection for "joueurs" and have a unique id for each joueur of your collection.

Comment: yes i'm agree whith you ! but i'm begginer and this i would like find a simple solution.

Comment: Yes i' m agree with you ! as you can see the picture "Joueur-Firebase" (attached field) my object has already a unique Id in Database Firebase.So i'm begginer and for me is more simple to sort my object "joueurClassement" and not change Collection for "joueurs".. you know an other methode to try a parametre object ?thanks